# Debugger and Integrated terminal gives different output for the c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, cmath

The following code's output is different when my integrated terminal is used and when the online editor (GeeksForGeeks)is used. It works perfectly fine on my IDE (Vscode, MingGW64 g++(8.1.0)). For example: for t = 1, x = 12 and p = 2, the output given by my IDE is 0 (correct) whereas the online editor gives 1 (wrong). The online editor uses g++(5.4). How is that the compilers vary so much over here? What should I do differently to solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void express(int x, int p, int &n_root, int &c, int curr_num)
{
    int power;

    for(int i = curr_num + 1; i <= n_root; ++i)
    {   
        power = pow(i, p);
        if(power < x) express(x - power, p, n_root, c, i);
        else break;
    }

    if(x == power) ++c;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    /*ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);*/

    int t, i;

    cin >> t;

    for(i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        int x, p, c, n_root;
        cin >> x >> p;
        c = 0;
        n_root = (int)pow(x, 1.0/p);
        express(x, p, n_root, c, 0);

        cout << c << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using uninitialized variables is bad practice in C++ and can lead to undefined behaviour. When compiling in debug mode they will be initialized, but in the optimized build their contents will be unknown.

Comment: @iwans I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: In express, if the for loop goes through 0 iterations then `power` will be used while uninitialized.

Comment: Well, the problem was actually the header file cmath. When I changed it to math.h, the code worked fine.